# Download attachment from encrypted / signed mail

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, smime, mimekit

I am trying to handle a signed and encrypted e-mail message. More precisely, I want to download an attached Excel file.

To my current knowledge, I own a pfx file (with password), which is an archive containing a private key to decrypt as well as a certificate (public key) to verify the mail sender.

**EDIT**

With the help of [jstedfast](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87117/jstedfast) I now present a working minimal example.

```
/* certificates */
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(
    privateKeyFullFileName,
    privateKeyPassword,
    X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
collection.Add(certificate);

/* smtp handling */
FindItemsResults<Item> inboxEMails = exchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(int.MaxValue));
EmailMessage eMail = // find appropriate mail
EmailMessage tmp = EmailMessage.Bind(ExchangeService, eMail.Id, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties));
foreach (Attachment attachment in tmp.Attachments) {
  FileAttachment fa = attachment as FileAttachment;
  fa.Load();
  /* decrypting */
  using (MemoryStream rawStream = new MemoryStream(fa.Content)) {
    EnvelopedCms envelopedCms = new EnvelopedCms();
    envelopedCms.Decode(rawStream.ToArray());
    envelopedCms.Decrypt(collection); // <- decrypting with .pfx file
    using (MemoryStream decryptedStream = new MemoryStream(envelopedCms.ContentInfo.Content)) {
      MimeKit.MimeEntity entity = MimeKit.MimeEntity.Load(decryptedStream);
      if (entity is MimeKit.Cryptography.ApplicationPkcs7Mime) {
        MimeKit.Cryptography.ApplicationPkcs7Mime p7m = entity as MimeKit.Cryptography.ApplicationPkcs7Mime;
        using (MimeKit.Cryptography.TemporarySecureMimeContext ctx = new MimeKit.Cryptography.TemporarySecureMimeContext()) {
          Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate cert = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(certificate);
            ctx.Import(cert);
            if (p7m.SecureMimeType == MimeKit.Cryptography.SecureMimeType.SignedData) {
              MimeKit.MimeEntity extracted;
              MimeKit.Cryptography.DigitalSignatureCollection signatures = p7m.Verify(ctx, out extracted);
              MimeKit.MimePart part = extracted as MimeKit.MimePart;
              if (part != null) {
                // TODO
              }
              MimeKit.Multipart multipart = extracted as MimeKit.Multipart;
              if (multipart != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < multipart.Count; ++i) {
                MimeKit.MimePart mimePart = multipart.ElementAt(i) as MimeKit.MimePart;
                if (mimePart != null && mimePart.IsAttachment) {
                  using (FileStream outStream = File.Create(/* path + */ mimePart.FileName)) {
                    try {
                      mimePart.Content.DecodeTo(outStream);
                    } catch { }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to Import with `p7m.Import(ctx);`? That's for importing `smime-type=certs-only` content, it won't decrypt or verify any signers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is a valid point. Does that mean I am already able to get the Excel file from the *decrytedStream*? I stored this stream to a file, but Excel was unable to open it.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the `decryptedStream` and assuming that it is an `application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=signed-data` MIME part, you started off correctly, but what you want to do instead of calling `Import()` is to call `Verify()` instead:

```
using (var decryptedStream = new MemoryStream (envelopedCms.ContentInfo.Content)) {
    var entity = MimeEntity.Load (decryptedStream);

    if (entity is ApplicationPkcs7Mime) {
        // Note: no need to create a new ApplicationPkcs7Mime part, just cast it!
        var p7m = (ApplicationPkcs7Mime) entity;
        using (var ctx = new TemporarySecureMimeContext ()) {
            // Import the X509Certificate2 into the S/MIME context
            var cert = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate (certificate);
            ctx.Import (cert);

            if (p7m.SecureMimeType == SecureMimeType.SignedData) {
                // Verify the content *and* extract the original content from the binary envelope
                MimeEntity extracted;

                var signatures = p7m.Verify (ctx, out extracted);

                // Save the Excel content to disk
                using (var stream = File.Create ("excel.xls")) {
                    var part = extracted as MimePart;

                    part.Content.DecodeTo (stream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. The code runs until `var part = extracted as MimePart` where `part` remains `null`.
Moreover, it is of type `application/x-pkcs7-mime` - please mind the *x*. Might this cause non-successful casting?

Comment: The x is not the problem. If part is null, then it means the extracted entity is not a MimePart. It is probably a Multipart.

Comment: Based on your proposal I offer a running minimal example in my edited initial question.